# How to only allow images to be accessed by logged in users

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently using Codeigniter/PHP and IIS 7

I have currently looked at "hotlinking" but that only protects images from being put onto other web sites. It doesn't stop the end user from directly pasting the image URL into the address bar and accessing the image whilst not being logged in.

I am not too sure what the best way is to approach this problem. How can you protect images so that it can only be accessed by logged in users?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put the images somewhere **outside** the webroot of the site.

Have a php script that gets the images and displays the images **only** when logged in.

Comment: Right, would a good way for doing this, be using a session variable say      $this->session->set_userdata(array('getImages'=>True)); and then wrap an if statement around the function which gets the images and displays it?

Comment: @thejoker sure. however you want to do it is fine ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be, if you stop using real url of images on the whole site and always retrieve the images via a php script(controller function) that could help you checking user authentication and other staffs like resize/crop/cache etc as well.

In that case, you can use any url even in root base, which isn't known to outside world at all.

Comment: What is the best way to do this programmically - not sure how to approach it? Would wrapping it around a session be the best way to do this?

Comment: No wait I have already implemented it that way - the problem is, in order to fetch the images in the first place it gets the real URL as you say. So all they need is that to directly access the folder with the images.

Comment: <?php
// Check permissions...
// If permissions OK:
$img = file_get_contents("C:/inetpub/obama.jpg");

// Send jpeg headers
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
// Dump out the image data.
echo $img;
exit();
?>

Am I on the right track. Cheers.

Comment: well, what path you are accessing in php, shouldn't be known to outside people right? How do you think other people is knowing "C:/inetpub/obama.jpg" path? can you please show me a example url which you are using for retrieving the image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455351/image-protection-in-codeigniter check this out. I have tried this. Almost got it working, but it isn't quite.

Answer (score 0):

There are perfomance issues in the above answer. You can rename the folder that containing images every hour / day ....
Ex

`images/a8s7d5r7w9/33229.png` to `images/g2j3s3l1p2t/33229.png`