# image protection in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, image, codeigniter

I am using the following code in my controller:

```
//function to protect images from being accessed directly.
function getImage($img_id){


      //code to authenticate user goes here then...
$url = $this->data['base_url'].'system/application/images/c/thumbs/';

$filepath = $url.$img_id;

    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  if(file_exists($filepath)){
    echo "we are here";
        $img_handle = imagecreatefromjpeg($filepath) or die("");
    echo $img_handle;
        ImageJpeg($img_handle);
    }



    }
```

In my view to fetch the images, I have used the following code:

```
<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Controller/getImage/obama.jpg' width="100px">
```

Now even though it is going into the controller, it is not displaying the image. The Obama file is in the correct directory. I have no idea why.

Comment: Let me guess: It is displaying a "broken" image. And that is correct, that is what you have programmed. Why do you expect it doing something different? And mull over your own stuff: Why does the debugging you introduced here does not work?

Comment: Yeah it is displaying a broken image. What I tried to do was to get the image id, pass that into the controller, which in turn returns the image to the view. Done this way, so that the end user does not know the url to the folder where the image is stored.

The debugging does not work, because it cannot find the file, despite the filepath being correct.

Comment: @thejkoker: Explaining what you want is only one part of debugging. You need to do basic debugging first. So let me ask again: Can you imagine why the debugging you're doing here does not work well?

Comment: because that segment of code is not being executed?

Comment: No, look closer: You echo text but you tell your browser that this is an image. That can not turn out well. It's like you expect some sweets but will get a bottle of salt.

Comment: Ah, the header. Thank you Hakre.
The if(file_exists($filepath)){ } does not seem to fare well. It's only after I remove that, it displays the image.  I dont understand why this is, obviously the image has to exist in order for it to display in the first place? Right.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are outputing text to the browser, and then the image. The browser will try to render the image but it will be corrupted.

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
if(file_exists($filepath)){
    echo "we are here";
    $img_handle = imagecreatefromjpeg($filepath) or die("");
    echo $img_handle;
    ImageJpeg($img_handle);
}
```

Also, if you want to do an `echo` you can't send an `header` saying "hey, this is a jpeg image".

Answer (score 0):

you sure the image can be accessed via $this->data['base_url'].'system/application/images/c/thumbs/obama.jpg , you tried accessing it on browser, right?

Also, avoid printing text before rendering the image, it may corrupt the image.

If still doesn't work, let us know the error page screenshot, whats its saying.

Comment: Ive got it to work, however I ran into the following issue: I have a file name which has spaces. So it would be like this: obama 1.jpg i.e. obama space 1 , the script cannot handle it and displays a broken image. Any idea how I can tweek it so that it can handle file names with spaces?

Comment: If you pass the local relative path to "file_exist()" method, then space won't be a problem. But, as I saw before, you are using url as the full path to image, so you will need to replace each space with "%20". Hope this will work. However, my recommendation is using local relative path to file_exist method. Like "file_exist("./system/application/images/test image with space.jpg")", which should work fine

Comment: Tried this : 
 $filepath = $url.file_exist($img_id); got a server error, URL is getImage/obama%201.JPG