# Dealing with filenames which have white spaces

Tags: php, codeigniter

My script here works fine:

[image protection in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455351/image-protection-in-codeigniter/11464734#11464734)

However it displays a broken image if my filename has a space, so say it is "obama 1.jpg".

To try and resolve this problem, I have used http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

And replaced all the white spaces in the img_id with "%"s.

But I have had no luck.  I cannot strip the white spaces out, so will have to make due with the structure of the string.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if it's cacking at `file_exists($filepath)` and $filepath should be a url, then perhaps you should `rawurlencode` the filename. http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the image just use

```
echo urlencode($image_name);
```

That should fix it!

Comment: $url = $this->data['base_url'].'system/application/images/c/thumbs/';
 $filepath = $url.urlencode($img_id);
I tried this, still got a broken image. It adds %20 so "obama%201.jpg" like that.

Comment: I stuck this in my controller class.

Comment: Please select this as the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Didn't work, but I will select this as an answer. BTW urlencode, what exactly is it? My final solution is to strip out all white spaces in the database and files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the filenames in URLs try replacing the space with %20 so "obama%201.jpg"