# How to show images in a webpage from root directory in PHP Codeigniter?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I have made a site with Codeigniter and users have options to upload their photos there. As the photos are personal, I think keeping them on web directory is not safe. As a result, I kept them on a root directory like `/var/www/images` directory. Now, how I can get the images in a webpage?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Choice dear learner. you images folder needs to be accessible by your code and to the browser to render that image by the image path. For example

[image]

This is the image directory of my project. I am using all these images in different pages of my website. Some are selected dynamically by my code.

Now in your case by putting images in www folder, you are making a path of http://images/ which is not recommended by any PHP guidelines. Your images folder should be in your project root not outside.

If you want to disable folders to be viewed, just add empty index.html file, but if you try to protect images from being viewed then your website wont be able to find them too [image protection in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455351/image-protection-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

The code will be as safe as you make it. Well what you are doing is fine, the web server will still have to access the images.

While ignoring the rest of your code or what yo are trying to achieve, you could try referencing the images fro your webroot or probably create a symlink.

Also, I would try to put the images in another place like AWS.

Answer (score 0):

If security is a concern for you, you can try building a ImagesController that checks if image exists, if user has permissions to see it and after that render it. 
Uploaded images should also have some reference row inside a table in your database that can have a column which specifies if it should be public (also try to sort them to folders depending on what it represents - user profile pics, product images, etc).
I know it's a little bit of work but this would be the way I would do it.
You can check online for examples of controllers that return an image.

Good luck on your project.